# NordVPN as Proxy server for PHP Curl request to HTTPS url

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I've got problems useing NordVPN as a proxy server to connect to an https://www.amazon.com.au url,

Comments are what I have tried, any help appreciated.

```
        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,8);
        //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'au695.nordvpn.com:443');     // PROXY details with port
        //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'au695.nordvpn.com:1080');     // PROXY details with port
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'au695.nordvpn.com:89');     // PROXY details with port
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxyauth);   // Use if proxy have username and password
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5); // If expected to call with specific PROXY type
        //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
        //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_HTTP);
```

debug is below

```
*   Trying 103.107.197.83:89...
* Connected to au695.nordvpn.com (103.107.197.83) port 89 (#0)
* allocate connect buffer
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to www.amazon.com.au:443
* Proxy auth using Basic with user 'GFascTQQaDBxHrZULS4vnCgg'
> CONNECT www.amazon.com.au:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.amazon.com.au:443
Proxy-Authorization: Basic R0Zhc2NUUVFhREJ4SHJaVUxTNHZuQ2dnOkxzV0g1eHQ0UTdoVnF0N2k5bkFZODlSUw==
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

* Recv failure: Connection was reset
* Received HTTP code 0 from proxy after CONNECT
* CONNECT phase completed
* Closing connection 0
```

It works fine when I disable to proxy settings.

Comment: Did you try to access https://www.amazon.com.au with same proxy config on browser ? it seems you block from amazon server.

Comment: It looks like a nordvpn thing, I tried a public proxu found online and it works, I think https isn't enabled or something.